# Monitor RabbitMQ with Prometheus outside kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, prometheus, grafana, bitnami

I'm trying to monitor a RabbitMQ set up in a kubernetes cluster by the bitnami helm chart with 3 pods from an Prometheus outside the cluster and I don't understand how that should be possible.

On the RabbitMQ the prometheus plugin is enabled, in the helm chart the metrics endpoint is enabled and a loadbalancer is configured to allow Prometheus to access /metrics at port 9419 of the loadbalancer.

But of course I see only the stats of one pod of the rabbitmq (the one the loadbalancer is routing to) but not all three.

How is this thought to work?

Do I need the prometheus-exporter and/or bitnami serviceMonitor and if yes, how does it need to be configured?